# dart, shelf_route: What is route name in the `GET` method that work with the request that using multi parameter?

Tags: dart, dart-shelf, dart-server

My flutter app sends the request to this API with the `GET` method and uses the `queryParameters` like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {'id': null};
parameters.updateAll((key, value) => Uri.encodeComponent(jsonEncode(value)));
String url= 'http://localhost:8080/test;
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url).replace(queryParameters: parameters);
final http.Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
```

The `URL` that was sent is `http://localhost:8080/test?id=null`

My route on the server side is:

```
final _route = shelf_router.Router()
  ..get("/test<id>", (Request request, String id) {
    return Response.ok('ok');
  })
  ..all('/<ignored|.*>', (Request request) {
    return Response.notFound('notFound');
  });
```

But my request from the flutter app always goes to the `all('/<ignored|.*>', (Request request){ ... }` route.
I have tried to change the route name in the `get("/test<id>", (Request request, String id){ ... }` from `"/test<id>"` to `"/test<id>"`, `"/test?<id>"`, `"/test?id<id>"`, or `"/test?id=<id>"` but there isn't working.

What is the correct route name?

And I want to use the route with n parameters(get these parameters by using `request.params[ ... ]`). What is the route name to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I missed this.
Just use the `"/test"`.

The parameters are `request.url.queryParameters`

example:

```
..get("/test", (Request request) {
  Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {...request.url.queryParameters};
  parameters.updateAll((key, value) => jsonDecode(Uri.decodeComponent(value)));
  print(parameters); //{id: null}
  return Response.ok('ok');
})
```